# Issue with creat bulk ad user by using import local machine csv as variable and pass to remote server

Tags: powershell, csv

I try to import local csv file and creat aduser in remote server. Both local machine and remote server are join domain. I can import csv in remote server and create aduser, but I don't know how to import local csv and pass to remote server.

It's show

```
cmdlet New-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
```

Here is my example.csv column name

```
LastName,FirstName,EmpolyID,LoginName,GroupName,OU
```

Here is my code.

```
$Users = Import-CSV E:\example.csv
$Session = New-PSSession -Computername server1 -Credential user@domain.com
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {
    Param($FirstName, $LastName, $EmpolyID, $OU, $GroupName)
    New-ADUser
    -Name ($FirstName + $LastName)
    -DisplayName ($FirstName + $LastName)
    -Surname $LastName
    -GivenName $FirstName
    -SamAccountName $EmpolyID
    -Path $OU
    -Description $User.EmpolyID
    -Enable $true
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
    -AccountPassword ConvertTo-SecureString "changpassfirst" -AsPlainText -Force
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $EmpolyID
    } -ArgumentList $User.FirstName, $User.LastName, $User.EmpolyID, $User.OU, $User.GroupName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Users = Import-CSV E:\example.csv
$Session = New-PSSession -Computername server1 -Credential user@domain.com
$Group = "MyGroup"

$code = {
    $GroupName = $using:group
    $userArray = $using:Users
    foreach ($user in $userArray){
        $paramsHt = @{
            Name=($user.FirstName + $user.LastName)
            DisplayName=($user.FirstName + $user.LastName)
            SurName=$user.LastName
            GivenName=$user.FirstName
            smaAccountName=$user.EmpolyID
            Path=$user.OU
            Description=$user.EmpolyID
            Enable=$true
            ChangePasswordAtLogon=$true
            AccountPassword=(ConvertTo-SecureString "changpassfirst" -AsPlainText -Force)
        }
        $null = new-aduser @paramsHt
        $null = Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $EmpolyID
    }
}

invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock $code
```

You try to access a variable available on the caller machine from a remote machine. You can do so by using $using, so you do not need the parameter -argumentlist. If you want to go the -argumentlist route you can access those values by indexing the array, e.g. $args[0].

There is no need to call invoke-command foreach user, you only want to connect to a single target machine so you only need to call it one time.

So in principle this would do the trick. But you will face another issue: kerberos double hop. You jump from machineA to machineB and execute code which calls machineC (Domain Controller) = double hop. You can workaround this issue by passing over credentials to the new-aduser cmdlet.

Is it really needed to jump on another machine, can't you talk to active directory from machineA?

Comment: Server1 is provide to team member to creat ad user, it's Microsoft tool with GUI.
`Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
At line:5 char:21
+ $userArray = $using:$Users`

Comment: sorry did a mistake, should be $using:users - I updated the code sample

Comment: Thanks for help. I use updated code to connect DC, it's seems the same issue. `cmdlet New-ADUser at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: Name:`

Comment: please show one element of the array $Users

Comment: `$Users.EmpolyID` show `testID`
and `$Users` will show `LastName    : Lab
FirstName   : testuser
EmpolyID    : testID
LoginName   : testuserLab
GroupName   : IT
OU          : OU=ADM
Description : OU=companyname`

Comment: My PSVersion  is 5.1.22000.832, my computer OS is win11.

Comment: ok did take time for me to see it: you did disconnect the parameters from the new-aduser cmdlet. You have to specify the parameters on the same line or use splatting like in my updated sample. So now we fixed: remote variable issue, invoke-command issue and the disconnected parameter issue... but as already said you probably will run into the double hop issue :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure out why by read your code. Have a nice day. I will try fo fix double hop issue.